# How to plot 95% confidence intervals for multiple factor data in ggplot2 R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mixed-models, confidence-interval

```
df <- data.frame (yaxis = rnorm(120,5,1),
                  xaxis = rep(c("A","B","C","D","E", "F"), times = 20),
                  factor = rep(c("1","2","3","4","5", "6"), each = 20))

df$xaxis <- as.factor(df$xaxis)
df$factor <- as.factor(df$factor )

library(lmerTest)
mod <- lmer(yaxis ~  xaxis + (1|factor), df)
mod.fit <- predictInterval(mod, df) 
df.fit <- cbind(df, mod.fit)

ggplot(df.fit, aes(x = xaxis, y  = yaxis, color = xaxis, group = xaxis)) + 
 geom_point() + 
 theme_classic() + 
 geom_errorbar(aes(min = lwr, max = upr), color = "black", width = 0.3)  + 
 geom_point(aes(y = mean(fit), x = xaxis), position = position_dodge(width = 0.25), color = "black",size = 5)
```

I want to plot the raw data with the predicted 95% CI and means. I tried the above but I get multiple confidence intervals for the fitted data. How can I correct it?

[image]

Comment: Do you only want a single mean and confidence interval at each value on the x axis or do you want six at each x axis location (i.e. one for each factor)?

Comment: I want single mean and CI corresponding to each x-axis location.

Comment: so how is that affected by the factor? Why do you need to extract this from the model, rather than by doing, say, a single confidence interval at each x axis location using `stat_summary`?

Comment: @AllanCameron Could you please check my solution if it is reasonable. I am not quite sure. Many thanks.

Comment: @AllanCameron: I am still using the CI and mean from the PredictInterval fit, so that is accounting for the random effect of the factor. I only want to plot the raw data against the predicted mean and CI. That's why I'm using the model. Does that help?

Comment: But `PredictInterval` isn't giving you means and confidence intervals for the data. It is showing you what the model _predicts_ for each combination of x axis value and factor, with a confidence interval around each prediction. This is a different concept from the mean and standard deviation of your data. Do you want the prediction and standard error for just the _fixed effects_ at each x axis location?

Comment: @TarJae I don't think that's quite right. The `mean(fit)` gives the same mean at all the x axis locations, and I don't think it is quite right to simply take an average of the upper and lower confidence intervals either (though I am no statistician)

Comment: @AllanCameron Ahhh!! I see what you are getting at. I was messing with the dataset and just realized that as well. Yes, I need just the prediction and 95% CI for just the fixed effects at each axis. I thought we could do that using the predict() function but I couldn't compute the CI [I haven't used it in a while]

Comment: @AllanCameron Do you know what function to use to predict fit and CI using ranom effects? predict() doesn't appear to do that anymore and predictInterval is the incorrect function to use

Comment: @Share see my solution below. This shows the predictions from the fixed effects at each x axis point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the fixed effect from your model using `summary(mod)$coefficients`. This allows you to get the prediction for each x axis value and calculate the 95% confidence interval of that prediction using simple arithmetic.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)

mod <- lmer(yaxis ~  xaxis + (1|factor) + 0, df)

summary_df <- summary(mod)$coefficients %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(xaxis = LETTERS[1:6]) %>%
  rename(yaxis = Estimate) %>%
  mutate(ymin = yaxis - 1.96 * `Std. Error`,
         ymax = yaxis + 1.96 * `Std. Error`)

ggplot(df, aes(x = xaxis, y  = yaxis, color = xaxis, group = xaxis)) + 
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), data = summary_df,
                width = 0.4, linewidth = 1, alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_point(color = 'black', size = 2, data = summary_df) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Dark2')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think you just need to add `library(dplyr)`

Comment: @Share dplyr and ggplot2 are loaded when you load `library(tidyverse)`, though a bit less overhead by calling `library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)`